# How can I create a new ConfigurationElement object using PowerShell or prevent a change to an existing one modifying its source?

Tags: arrays, powershell, iis

I am using the WebAdministration module for IIS management through PowerShell and wish to create a new ConfigurationElement object to append onto an array of existing ConfigurationElements.

Once done, the modified array will be applied back to the IIS site.

At the moment I am trying to make a copy of an existing ConfigurationElement object in an array, but every time I modify the item, the original gets modified too. I know about PowerShell arrays and references so I have been taking the original array, cloning it, then accessing an item in the cloned array to make a 'copy' of. This is the 'copy' I modify, but I find that the original object from the cloned array also gets modified.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$siteName = "MySite"
$site = Get-Website | Where { $_.Name -eq $siteName }
$foundSite = $site.Name

# Switch to IIS sites
cd IIS:\Sites

# Get our current IIS Site bindings collection from the site.
$bindingCollection = Get-ItemProperty $foundSite -Name bindings

# Clone the collection array
$tempBindingCollection = $bindingCollection.Collection.Clone()

# We now do our modifications in the cloned/copied array, so as not to affect our main array which will be sent back
# to IIS to configure the bindings later on...
$newBinding = $tempBindingCollection[0]
$newBinding.protocol = "net.tcp"
$newBinding.bindingInformation = $NetTCPBindingValue

# Now at this point, $newBinding has changed (the protocol and bindingInformation properties), but so has the original $bindingCollection.Collection[0] object!!
# I only want $newBinding to change.
```

So my question is - how can I either

A) Create my own ConfigurationElement object using PowerShell, so I don't have to clone an existing ConfigurationElement, or

B) Prevent my cloned/copied ConfigurationElement from updating it's source when I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this in a complicated way - the answer is simply to use the New-WebBinding cmdlet to add a new binding to the site, rather than modify the existing bindingCollection and apply it back.

An example to add a net.tcp binding would be:

```
New-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "net.tcp" -Port 334 -IPAddress *
```